# Defining a proto message from a .proto file

Tags: .net, angular

I just joined an established .NET team/project but do not have any .NET experience - and am trying to diagnose why my .proto file isn't behaving as expected.

The .proto file has a message that was originally defined with two fields (say, userId and year).  It's pretty simple and looks something like this (as an aside... it is currently working):

```
message <InformationRequest> {
   string user_id = 1;
   int32 year = 2;
}
```

Essentially the message is handling some inputs to a query.

I would like to update the message with a third label, so something like:

```
message <InformationRequest> {
   string user_id = 1;
   int32 year = 2;
   string my_string = 3;

}
```

I've updated the original call in the controller using camel case with an initial capital letter (essentially just followed the convention modeled online), but I'm getting the following error:

error CS0117 'InformationRequest' does not contain a definition for 'MyString'

Essentially, no matter how I build/compile my project (i.e. changing build order, commenting out my call to InformationRequest, etc.) I'm getting an error that this definition doesn't exist.  The bugaboo though is that when I open the "InformationRequest" class that's built - it *does* have MyString defined.

Any advice or help here?  I've spent a few hours of my life trying to debug this and I'm not getting any traction...

Tried:
-Changing build order
-Double checking all naming/case conventions
-Looking at the file created by the .proto call to ensure there is actually a definition

Comment: Can you share how did you define `InformationRequest`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up deleting the .bin and .obj files, rebuilt the project, and that worked.  Interestingly it didn't to "clean" the project... I had to manually delete and rebuild.